# Adding new objects in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm training in Vue.js by doing a quiz. I did a submit system and deleting a questions. But i want to add a Question adder. I tried this:

```
addQuestion()
    {
        if (this.question != "") {
            this.questions.push(this.question);
            this.question = "";
        }
        else
        {
            alert("You didnt write a question")
        }
    }
```

but that didnt works. Any help? Full code:

HTML:

```
    <body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="question" v-for="(question, index) in questions">
            <h2>{{ question.question }}</h2><button @click="deleteQuestion(index)" class="doprava"><img src="criss.png"/></button>
            <label v-for="answer in question.answers" class="answer" :class="{ 'answer-correct':answer.correct, 'answer-false':answer.false }">
                <input type="checkbox" :value="answer.id" v-model="question.selected"> {{ answer.answer }}
            </label>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <button @click="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
        <button @click="addQuestion()">Add Question</button><br><br>
        <label >Question: </label>
        <input v-model="question" type="text"><br><br>
        <label v-model="answer-correct">Correct Answer: </label>
        <input type="text"><br><br>
        <label v-model="answer-false">Answer: </label>
        <input type="text"><br><br>
        <label v-model="answer-false">Answer: </label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="questions.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
    questions: questions,
    result: 0
},
methods: {
    onSubmit() {
        this.result = 0

        this.questions.forEach(question => {
            question.answers.forEach(answer => {
                answer.correct = question.correct.includes(answer.id);
                answer.false = question.false.includes(answer.id);
            });
        });
    },
    deleteQuestion(index) 
    {        
        this.questions.splice(index, 1);
    },
    addQuestion()
    {
        if (this.question != "") {
            this.questions.push(this.question);
            this.question = "";
        }
        else
        {
            alert("You didnt write a question")
        }
    }
}
```

});

Questions in JS:

```
var questions = [
{
    question: "1+1 is",
    answers: [ 
        { id: 0, answer: "1", correct: false }, 
        { id: 1, answer: "0", correct: false }, 
        { id: 2, answer: "2", correct: false } 
    ],
    correct: [2],
    selected: [],
    false: [0, 1]
},
{
    question: "Is Donald Trump egoistic?",
    answers: [ 
        { id: 0, answer: "Yes", correct: false }, 
        { id: 1, answer: "No", correct: false }
    ],
    correct: [0],
    selected: [],
    false: [1]
}
```

];

Answer (score 1):

Any properties which you use in a `v-model` attribute for an input field should first be declared in `data` to make them reactive.

Here you are using `question`, `answer-correct` and `answer-false` in `v-model`. These should all be declared in `data`. Also, you are using `answer-false` twice, meaning both of these inputs will resolve to the same value. If you want to have multiple values here, you may want to create `answer-false-a` and `answer-false-b` or something like that.

You can add these to `data` like this:

```
data: {
    questions: questions,
    result: 0,
    question: '',
    answer-correct: '',
    answer-false-a: '',
    answer-false-b: ''
},
```

Comment: And how can I add it in data?

Comment: I've added that to my example.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your js code with this

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
    questions: questions,
    result: 0,
    question: {
      question: "",
      answers: [],
      correct: [],
      selected: [],
      false: []
     }
},
methods: {
    onSubmit() {
        this.result = 0

        this.questions.forEach(question => {
            question.answers.forEach(answer => {
                answer.correct = question.correct.includes(answer.id);
                answer.false = question.false.includes(answer.id);
            });
        });
    },
    deleteQuestion(index) 
    {        
        this.questions.splice(index, 1);
    },
    addQuestion()
    {
        if (this.question != "") {
            this.questions.push(Object.assign({},this.question)); // this is to avoid pushing an object with the same reference address. A better way is to use the cloneDeep option from lodash library which can clone an object with multiple nested elements.
            this.question = "";
        }
        else
        {
            alert("You didnt write a question")
        }
    }
}
```